# Is there any reference materials on complexity analysis for lazy languages?

Tags: complexity-theory, programming-languages, functional-programming, haskell

Is there any books, papers or articles on how to analyze the time complexity of programs written in lazy languages such as Haskell?

I know how laziness is implemented and how it can be expanded and thus analyzed, but is there any "intuitive" methods that does not go deep into the low level implementation principles of lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

You could do worse than Chris Okasaki's *Purely Functional Data Structures*. It was published as a book, [but here's the thesis version](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/students/okasaki.pdf).

Another couple of theses that I haven't read, but may be worth trying to track down:

Meira, S.R.L., *On the efficiency of applicative algorithms.* PhD thesis, Computer Laboratory, University of Kent, p. 36. March 1985.

Stoye, W.,. *The implementation of functional languages using custom hardware.* PhD thesis, Computer Lab., University of Cambridge. May 1985.